# Cannot create a row of size 8079 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am including Navigational properties to my object like this :

```
IList<Job> jobs = myjobs
.Include(i => i.Bank)
.Include(i => i.Company)
.Include(i => i.Person)
....
ToList();
```

After this I process the list like this :

```
foreach(Job job in jobs)
{
WorkResult workresult = new WorkResult();
workresult.BankName = job.Bank.BankName;
workresult.CompanyName = job.Company.CompanyName;
....
}
```

There are like 30 lines of includes. Therefore I get the error in the title. How can I reduce column count to 8060? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need the ToList?

Comment: Yeah, after includes, I'm working on that list.

Comment: how? can you post a lilte bit more code?

Comment: The limit exists for *storing*, not querying. Post the code that actually inserts or updates an object, not the code that queries. Also post the *full* exception (ie including the call stack) which you can get with `Exception.ToString()` and the code where the exception actually occurs

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos would that work if I post the stacktrace?

Comment: @tire0011 I edited my question.

Comment: you don't need the ToList()

Comment: @tire0011 what should I use instead of that?

Comment: what type is myjobs?

Comment: Post the actual code that throws and *the full exception*. That error is *not* thrown when querying. Where does it occur? The call trace will tell you where the error occured and I'd bet that it doesn't include `ToList()`

Comment: @tire0011 `IQueryable<Job>`

Comment: Apart from that, if you want to copy data from one table to another, write an `INSERT` statement. There is absolutely no reason to send the data to the client if you simply want to copy it from one table to another with some modifications

Comment: @tire0011 what should I use instead of ToList()?

Comment: I think @PanagiotisKanavos is right. But you can remove the ToList() you dont need it.

Comment: @jason you *don't* need `ToList()` to load the data. The data is loaded when the query is *enumerated*, typically by calling `foreach`. In fact, `ToList` enumerates over an IQueryable or IEnumerable and inserts each item in a List<T>.